# Output the entire contents of a specific div from a URL

Tags: php

I'm using [Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), how can I output the entire contents of `.product-area`? It contains a lot of content so I just want to output it as is rather than loop through all the child divs.

Is that possible?

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = get_the_permalink();
$html = file_get_html($url);
$content = $html->find('div[class=product-area]');
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` returns an array, so you need to specify the index of the element you wish to select as the second parameter to the function call. See the comment in the second code example block on the site:

> // Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found
>   (zero based)

The following example should work well for your needs:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url     = get_the_permalink();
$html    = file_get_html($url);
$content = $html->find('.product-area', 0);
```

To get the text content of the `.product-area`, you need to access the `plaintext` property:

```
echo $content->plaintext;
```

Comment: Thanks, will that grab all the content within `product-area`... all the divs included?

Comment: @Rob yes, but you need to use `plaintext`. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant will that keep all child elements in tact? I essentially want to grab an entire page without the header and footer but there's a lot going on inside.

Comment: @Rob yes, it will.